# row to column conversion in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting

I have a script which gives me output like this

```
10.230.146.10:   Terminal ID        Gol
10.230.146.10:   Far End ID            pol
10.230.146.10:   Number of E1s     4E1s
10.230.146.10:    Packet link capacity  63Mbit/s
```

And I need output as

```
10.230.146.10.  Terminal ID.  Far End ID.  Number of E1s.   Packet link Capacity
Gol.      Pol.    4E1.     63Mbit/s
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
awk '{if($1 == ip) {$1=""; printf "%s ", $0} else {ip=$1; printf "\n%s ", $0;}}' input.txt
```

It will print an extra newline in the beginning of the output, but I don't think this is a problem.

For the the bellow sample input:

```
10.230.146.10: A B
10.230.146.10: C D
10.230.146.11: E F
10.230.146.11: G H
```

This script produces:

```
10.230.146.10: A B  C D 
10.230.146.11: E F  G H
```

Comment: 10.230.146.10: A C  E G 
10.230.146.11: B D  F H i need output like this.